# Raise an event in main whenever a variable's value changed in a class in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a changed event in a class, which is triggered at a variable's value change but I dont know how to send a notification to the main of my C# windows form, for example, show a message box to notify the value changed. I dont wanna set a timer to check every second for a response. There is any better way?

Comment: Show some code to explain your question - what's the "changed event" and why can't you use it for notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other posted you should impement INotifyPropertyChanged, but in addition I would suggest the following as well:

1. In the setter of your property check whether the value, that is assigned to your property really changes the property's value. Otherwise you probably fire the notify change to often.
2. You should also implement ISupportInitialize. Usually, you fire the property changed event to inform your main form that data has changed and needs to be saved. But if you load your instances from e.g. a database, the property changed event would also fire, indicating data has changed, which is not true in that sense. With ISupportInitialize you can tell your instances that they are being initialized and that they should not fire the notify property changed event.

Here is some sample code:

```
class MyTest : INotifyPropertyChanged, ISupportInitialize
{
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged;
public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
private bool _IsInitializing;

private bool _MyProperty;
public void BeginInit()
{
    _IsInitializing = true;
}

public void EndInit()
{
    _IsInitializing = false;
}

public bool MyProperty {
    get { return _MyProperty; }
    set {
        if (_MyProperty == value)
            return;

        _MyProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (_IsInitializing)
        return;
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
}
```

For initialization you would write (to prevent the property changed event from firering):

```
MyTest thisTest = new MyTest();
thisTest.BeginInit();
thisTest.MyProperty = true;
thisTest.EndInit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for `INotifyPropertyChanged`, a common pattern in WPF but it can also be used for Windows Forms. There is a pretty large example on the documentation page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

```
class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int foo;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Foo
    {
       get { return foo; }
       set
       {
          if (foo == value)
             return;
          foo = value;
          PropertyChanged("Foo");
       }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Please note that much of this becomes safer and much less boilerplate [you use newer .NET features](http://danrigby.com/2015/09/12/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-6-way/) such as `[CallerMemberName]`

Comment: How do I get this int value in the main class, for example, in a textblock? It will update automatically in the windows form? I never used this iNotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: You subscribe to the event in the form, and when the event is triggered you set the controls text to the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your variable with a "**Property**" (Getter and Setter).

Then you can implement in the "Setter" either your own event, or you can trigger the property changed event from WPF (if you are using WPF).